# How to work on VideoFrame after applying ShaderEffect

Tags: qt, shader, qml, qt-quick

(Sorry for my bad english)

I want to work on a QVideoFrame after applying a ShaderEffect. I use a QObject based class with a writable videoSurface property that can accept a QAbstractVideoSurface based class

```
class VideoProducer : public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractVideoSurface * videoSurface READ videoSurface WRITE setVideoSurface)

    public:
        ....

    private:
        QAbstractVideoSurface *video_surface;

    public slots:
        // function to present frame
        void onNewVideoContentReceived(const QVideoFrame &frame);
};
```

In my main.cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    VideoProducer videoProducer;
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    // to use videoProducer in QML
    viewer.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("videoProducer", &videoProducer);
    ....
}
```

In my main.qml file:

```
VideoOutput {
    id: videoOutput
    objectName: "videoOutput"
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: videoProducer
    visible: true
}
```

And the Shader Effect

```
ShaderEffect {
    property variant source: ShaderEffectSource {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: second_window
        live: true
        sourceItem: videoOutput
    }

    anchors.fill: parent
    fragmentShader: "...."
}
```

Now I want to bring the Frame (after shader effect) in C++ to make some operations on it...   can anyone help me?